How to implement Github Oauth2 in a FARM stack app the secure way?
I am trying to implement a github authentification on my stack (FastAPI, React).

The user gets a homepage with a 'start' button.
The button triggers a redirect to github authorize.
Github sends a code for authentication which I send to my API that posts to https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token with the client_id and secret_key. Then the API returns an access_token to the frontend.
The frontend stores the token in localStorage
The frontend uses localStorage.getItem('accesstoken') to send requests to the api.

My problem is this flow seems not very secure. The token is visible in inspect > application tab in my browser. My question is should I hash it and keep it in the localStorage or should I store it in the database.
I tried to read from FastAPI docs but it's not specific to my issue since I am more confused about React's role in this.

It will be insecure if secret_key is accessible from somewhere. Otherwise, what you have described above is a common approach - storing the access token in the local storage. Yes, the access token can have a certain set of permissions that the user granted on the authorization flow, but it is saved in the client's device (in this case, the browser), and no one else can access that storage and gather the token as it is not shared between different URL origins. Also, if you use FastAPI, you can integrate fastapi-oauth2 in a few steps by following the documentation and also ensure your server-side security.
